# How can I join orderers from two organisations with Minifabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, minifab

Good morning, I have an issue with Minifabric and I need to be able to resolve it.
I have the following infrastructure generated on two different computers:

--> Computer 1:

```
CA: "ca01.domain01.net"
Peer 1: "peer01.org01.domain01.net".
Peer 2: "peer02.org01.domain01.net"
Orderer: "ord-fabric01.domain01.net"
```

--> Computer 2:

```
CA: "ca01.domain02.es"
Peer 1: "peer01.org02.domain02.es"
Peer 2: "peer02.org02.domain02.es"
Orderer: "ord-fabric01.domain02.es"
```

I have joined both organisations by following tutorials such as the following:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1Ab57IrgZg
https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/minifabric/blob/main/docs/AddNewOrganization.md
```

When I finish, both organisations are joined correctly, but I start the "Hyperledger Explorer" tool and only the orderer of the first organisation appears and I need both orderers to appear.
How can I make both orderers join the same channel? Thank you for your time and dedication.

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue?